# How to display Wacom preferences in English

Tags: locale, bamboo

I own a Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch and have installed the drivers under a localized version of Windows 7. I would like to know whether there is a way to have the Wacom Preferences application display the various headings in English rather than in my Windows 7 operating system's locale.